# httpd.conf not found in /etc/apache2/

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I'm configuring CGI in my system ubuntu 14.04. But there is no `httpd.conf`. I have no idea what to do. I tried this command

```
#find / -name httpd.conf
```

didn't give any result.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you run the "find" command as root?

Comment: yes, I'm as root user @Kent

Comment: Hmm... I see that some recent Linux distros have used "apache2.conf" instead of "httpd.conf".  If apache is already running, you might re-run the find command to look for "apache2.conf", or just check in /etc/httpd/ to see what you can find.

Comment: I have `apache2.config`. For cgi configuration it needs `ScriptAlias` line. But apache2.con don't have it.

Comment: You should be able to add the same configuration directives to apache2.conf as what you would normally add to httpd.conf

Comment: it's not working... @Kent

Comment: You should probably open a new question, because the trouble of the missing config file is solved and people who can help with other cgi issues are unlikely to check this question.

Answer (score 4):

The configuration is probably in a `apache2.conf` file instead. You can either use that one or include a custom `httpd.conf` from that file.